# How to respond with message if option is true

Tags: python, if-statement, discord, discord.py

So, I am fairly new to this (30 minutes of experience as of right now) and an trying to get my Discord bot to display a message when one option of a command is used. But it just isn't working.

```
async def cmd_warn(self, message, user_mentions, option):
    """
    Usage:
        {command_prefix}warn [ spam | racism | discrimination | inappropriate | inpersonating | arguing | rudeness | harassment ] @UserName [@UserName2 ...]

    Warn users for spam / racism / discrimination / inappropriate / inpersonating / arguing / rudeness / harassment
    """

    if not user_mentions:
        raise exceptions.CommandError("**Error:** No users listed.", expire_in=20)

    if option not in ['spam', 'racism', 'discrimination', 'inappropriate', 'inpersonating', 'arguing', 'rudeness', 'harassment']:
        raise exceptions.CommandError(
            '**Invalid reason:** Use !help warn for more info!' % option, expire_in=20
        )

    for user in user_mentions.copy():
        if user.id == self.config.owner_id:
            print("[Commands:Warn] The owner cannot be warned (Tyler rigged).")
            user_mentions.remove(user)

    old_len = len(self.blacklist)

    if option in ['spam']:
        return Response('( %s ) You were warned for spam!')
        )
```

Comment: Are you on the rewrite branch? Are you using the commands extension? What is the `self` doing?  Is this a method in some class?

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True):
async def warn(ctx, option, *members: discord.Member):
    if not members:
        raise commands.CommandError('Must mention at least one user')
    if option.lower() not in ['spam', 'racism', 'discrimination', 'inappropriate',
                              'inpersonating', 'arguing', 'rudeness', 'harassment']:
        raise commands.CommandError('Invalid reason: {}'.format(option))
    for member in members:
        if member.id == config.owner_id:
            print('Owner cannot be warned') 
        else:
            await bot.say('{} you have been warned for {}'.format(member.mention, option))
```

This is a basic version of what you're trying to accomplish.  Note that `CommandError` is in the `discord.ext.commands` module.  I'm also directly interacting with the channel here.

I encourage you to switch to the rewrite branch when possible, only because it has [documentation for the `commands` extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/index.html#extensions) that the async branch lacks.